# How to execute AWS SSM automation document script daily?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, aws-ssm

**Background:**
I am trying to generate patch compliance data report in quicksight. In order to do it I am using terraform I have added all inventory data in S3 bucket.

I have created Athena automation document which creates database/tables in Athena using S3 bucket data. Now I want to add some terraform code which execute automation document daily on scheduled time.
For more information about this task: https://reinvent2019.awsmanagement.tools/mgt410/en/cont.html

**Problem:**
I can create maintenance window to define crone job for automation task but I do not have target to add.
My Athena Automation script is only creating/updating database in the Athena.There is no role of target here.

Can someone guid me on this issue?
Thank you in advance

Comment: What about CloudWatch Event rule based on your schedule with target of automation?

Comment: Thanks Marcin for your response. I will try with CloudWatch Event Rule.

Comment: Ok. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I created CloudWatch event rule to execute Automation Document manually. I checked in a Cloudtrail and found the following error:
"errorCode": "InvalidAutomationExecutionParametersException",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [CloudWatch Event that triggers on schedule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Scheduled-Rule.html) and calls Lambda function, that in turn invokes you Athena logic. Here is the good example: https://thedataguy.in/automate-aws-athena-create-partition-on-daily-basis/

Note on QuickSight - if you are using Spice, instead of direct query - you need to manage Spice rebuild too. Which might be tricky... The default setting only allow for once-a-day rebuild on schedule.